# How to use hotkeys in manifest file to launch extension default popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, add-on, manifest.json

Chrome extension noob here, I'm trying to write a `manifest.json` for an extension so that the extension's popup (hotbox.html) launches while hitting the `Command+Shift+0` on my keyboard.

I have the following code, however, it does nothing when I try to use my supposed shortcut. I have verified that the shortcut does not conflict with any other that I know of, I've also tried installing and uninstalling the extensions, but it doesn't work.

I am also getting no error messages. Any ideas? Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Composure",
    "description": "Test Extension",
    "version": "2.13.2",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "content/img/logo.png",
        "default_popup": "content/hotbox.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["content/hotbox.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "commands": {
        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "mac": "Command+Shift+0"
            }
        },

        "_execute_page_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "mac": "Command+Shift+1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the Shortcut to Command+Shift+1 and removed the "_execute_page_action", uninstall and reinstall and it works now. Wish this could somehow work with just the "Spacebar"

Comment: those keyboard shortcuts must start with `<Ctrl>` or `<Alt>` modifier keys... hard to believe one would wish to run a script whenever pressing `<Space>`; just count the blanks in between the words.

Comment: It makes sense to use the space bar depending on the site where you run the extension, specially if the primary purpose of the page is not related to typing words.

Comment: You could listen for Space using the the `window.addEventListener()` api, since I presume the window will be open when you need to be notified that the user pressed "Space".

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `"_execute_page_action":` & reinstall. That should work.